# Facebook Graph API: FQL Requests Older Than 30 Days

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm a bit confused. 
The docs say:

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or
>   50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific
>   fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >)
>   to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

So I tried, for example:

```
NSString *fqlStr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time > %d AND created_time < %d",dayBefore,dayAfter];
```

This was meant to display all posts between the day before and the day after my birthday... 
Which sorta worked..but it only was able to grab like 8 posts... and the posix dates are correct I checked them in a calculator..and its weird when I adjust the times a bit..like making the dayBefore earlier and the dayAfter later...I get a different set of posts but still only like 10....should I do a multiquery in like...1 hour intervals? Whats the reason for this?

-Josh

Comment: How many posts are there actually in that time? 8?

Comment: Lol no ..more..a lot more.. birthday :) ..when doing it in 1 hour chunks I end up with like 50-60. But it feels inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding LIMIT 5000 to the end of your query.

Comment: it gave me 6 months old post